# Azure AD B2C, can we programmatically sign up/sign in user from app to azure ad within the application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I don't want the appilcation to open "login.microsftonline.com.". 
I want it to be within my application. My own url I want to use. Is that possible ?

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joYAA.png)

Answer (score 2):

Per my understanding , you want to implement your own frontend to sign in/sign up users.So generally , this frontend will collect users' information and call B2C APIs to finish the sign in/sign up process .

It is realizable, for sigin in users, you can use **Azure B2C ROPC flow**. You can sigin users by users' username and password via REST API calling . Details [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc) .

For sign up users , you can use Azure AD Graph API to do that , details , you can refer to [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview#consumer-user) .

If you have any further concerns , pls feel free to let me know .

Comment: Hi @Pravindmaha , how is going now ? Has your issue be solved ?